# How can I access the HTML stored in a jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of buttons and and respective dialog box messages that I want to show when each of these buttons are clicked.

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="btn dialogbtn dialogbtn-save" href="#">Save</a>
<a class="btn dialogbtn dialogbtn-delete" href="#">Delete</a>

<div class="dialogstack">
  <div class="dialog-save">
    <p class="header">Save Header Text</p>
    <p class="message">Save Message Text</p>
    <p class="footer">
      <span>OK</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dialog-delete">
    <p class="header">Delete Header Text</p>
    <p class="message">Delete Message Text</p>
    <p class="footer">
      <span>Save</span>
      <span>Cancel</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to match the "save" and "delete" part when a button is clicked and have the related messages show up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dialogMessages = $("[class|='dialog']");

    $(".dialogbtn").on('click', function(){            
        var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
        if(index) {
          var dd = this.className.substring(index+1);
          var lastIndex = dd.indexOf(' ');
          var dialogFunction = dd.substring(0,(lastIndex>0)?lastIndex:dd.length);
        }

        if(dialogMessages.hasClass('dialog-'+dialogFunction)){
            var currentDialog = dialogMessages.find('.dialog-'+dialogFunction);
            alert($(currentDialog).find('p').text()); //This doesn't work
        }
    });
});
```

I am unable to access the HTML stored in the jquery objects. How can I fix this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/gynh4nwb/**

Comment: Make sure you're actually selecting an element. Otherwise, if you want HTML, why not use `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wish I could tell you why this works, but I don't actually know.

If you replace find with filter, it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dialogMessages = $("[class|='dialog']");

    $(".dialogbtn").on('click', function(){            
        var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
        if(index) {
          var dd = this.className.substring(index+1);
          var lastIndex = dd.indexOf(' ');
          var dialogFunction = dd.substring(0,(lastIndex>0)?lastIndex:dd.length);
        }

        if(dialogMessages.hasClass('dialog-'+dialogFunction)){
            var currentDialog = dialogMessages.filter('.dialog-'+dialogFunction);
            alert($(currentDialog).find('p').text());
        }
    });
});
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gynh4nwb/5/)

What is really odd about this is that your code works, with find, if dialogMessages is defined as:

```
var dialogMessages = $('div');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this function to print/alert HTML from div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var dialogMessages = $("[class|='dialog']");

        $(".dialogbtn").on('click', function(){            
            var index = this.className.indexOf('-');
            var dd = this.className.substring(index+1);             

                alert($(".dialog-"+dd).html()); //This doesn't work

    }); });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rohitbatta/gynh4nwb/3/

Comment: I end up with the same problem again. I have html stored in a jquery variable and I can't access `p.header`

Comment: You could try `$(<element>).filter( 'p .header' ).text()` to fetch information from variable
[Jquery API FILTER](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)